# Creating two Interdependent Dropdownlists using jquery/ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two dropdownlist boxes.one is for selecting countries and the other is for selecting states.The requiurement is if i select country dropdownlist box and choose a  country from it then automatically the corresponding states of that country have to appear in the states dropdownlist box using jquery or ajax in php.(for some countries state field will be empty,at that time the state select box should show empty text box) 
can any one suggest the solution
thanks in advance.....

Comment: Have you tried something yet or are you asking for code? Mind posting your work?

Comment: Refer this http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: I tried that using javascript, but i didn't got the solution wat i was looking for that's y i asked here...and i dont' know how to do this thing using jquery and ajax....if u know how to do that help me else pleaseeeeeeeeeee carry on with ur work....

Answer (score 2):

IN HTML

```
<select id="Country"></select>
<select id="State"></select>
```

IN SCRIPT

```
var Country = ['NEPAL', 'USA', 'CHINA'];
var NepalState = ['Gandaki', 'Bagmati'];
var USAState = ['Texas', 'California'];
var ChinaState = ['Phing', 'xing'];
$('#Country').change(function() {
    var stateOption=''; 
var countryvar = $('#Country option:selected').val();
switch (countryvar) {
case 'NEPAL':
    $.each(NepalState, function(index, value) {
        stateOption += '<option>' + value + '</option>';
    });
    break;
case 'USA':
    $.each(USAState, function(index, value) {
        stateOption += '<option>' + value + '</option>';
    });
    break;
case 'CHINA':
    $.each(ChinaState, function(index, value) {
        stateOption += '<option>' + value + '</option>';
    });
    break;
}
$('#State').html('');
$('#State').append(stateOption);
});
var CountryOption='';
$.each(Country, function(index, value) {
CountryOption += '<option>' + value + '</option>';

});
$('#Country').append(CountryOption); 
$('#Country').trigger('change');
```

All you have to do is load the options in second select when the first one is changed with respect to the value of the select changed.
A  Demo is in http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/YSMN3/4/